# What is the rough architecture of a Gmail-esque favorite/star feature?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, redux, amazon-dynamodb

I should start off by saying the stack we're currently using. However, we're open to other suggestions, since this problem - which comes down mainly to a response time problem - is pretty prevalant throughout our app.

**Backend**: AWS ELB EC2 instance with NodeJS, Restify, other assorted libraries, connected to DynamoDB.

**Front-end**: React with Redux.

I'm trying to build a feature that archives certain pieces of data on our React-based Front-end. In practice, this is very similar to "starring" or "favoriting" a post or email, like in Gmail or <--- right over there, with StackOverflow.

To me, this seems like a really simple problem on the surface. But as I delve in to it a little more, it gets more complex.

The main problem comes from one fact: if I click on the "star" icon, it should generate a request and change its image. However, in most cases, I would wait for a response before changing the corresponding value on the front-end, to prevent conflicts. The problem is, our request times are way too long for that. Gmail and SO shows the transition between starred and un-starred instantly, and I feel users would not be happy if it was anything but that for this feature.

If I just allowed it to change freely on the frontend and disregard the responses from the requests it generates, I run in to race and conflict issues very quickly. Especially when considering we want to be able to "Select All" and star (archive) on a table 200+ records long.

So what's the answer here? I'm completely at a loss, to be honest.

Comment: You "predict" the result on the front-end (show the star) and adjust it if the response disagrees with your prediction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the concept that might be helpful here is "optimistic UI". This is a pattern commonly used for what you're describing to keep a tight feedback loop to the user, indicating to them that their action has done something, assuming a positive outcome while something (e.g. an HTTP request) runs asynchronously, and if there are errors you can revert the positive state and alert the user to an issue.

In practice in React, if you're using something like Redux, you could create some kind of "archive" action that sets the state for each selected item as "archived" in the reducer, and at the same time shoot off the request to the backend to update the server with the archived state. Assuming you use `async/await` to create the server request, you could wrap it in a `try/catch` where the `catch` detects a failed request and reverts the "archived" state of the selected items in the reducer, and probably shows an error message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, I think the best approach is to "hope for the best".

The user is expecting there to be no issue when they press the star button, so doing anything besides lighting up the star will be alarming to the user. Of course you need to validate the star on your backend, but in the mean time you will assume that it will be successful and light the star up.

When the request has been completed, assuming everything has worked and the star was valid, the user does not notice anything, and the interaction has worked just how they expected it to.

If the request finishes and the star was invalid for some reason, you will have to display some type of error message and un star the item.